# Mongoose delete item from MongoDB array

Tags: arrays, mongoose, save

I've tried several ways and now I'm stacked.
I have a caollection named users where each document has a field named 'feature' defined in the following way within the schema

```
    feature: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Feature'
    }
```

I'm tryind to update the feature field in this way but I' don't know how to save. Actually 'data' contains the updated array but I'm not able how to save it in the db

```
const delete_menu = async (req,res) => {
const toObject = true
    const feature = await UsrFeature.find( { }, 'feature', {lean:toObject}, (err, data) => {
            data.map(async (i) => {
                var index = i.feature.indexOf(req.body._id)
                if(index > -1) {i.feature.splice(index, 1)}
                
                
            })
            res.status('200').json(data)
        } 
    )
    await feature.save()
}
```

Of course await feature.save() doesn't work

Comment: You should do `data.save()` inside the callback.

Comment: Already done without success. It report data.save is not a function. Should it be related to the lean() usage?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It is due to the `lean` option only, which removes the save method, getters/setters, virtuals, or other Mongoose features and returns a plain JS object. And since you're using callback it won't return anything. So, you cant use `feature.save()` either.

Comment: Thanks. Finally I review my code.and.I get it working changing.all.the logic and semplifying a bit. Many thanks